# CloudFormation optional parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to have some conditional parameters in cloud formation that are showed in AWS Console only in particular case.

```
Parameters:
  A:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
    - x
    - y
  B:
    Type: Number
    Default: 3
```

Expected result during stack creation in browser AWS Console (*CloudFormation -> Stacks -> Create Stack*).

> If parameter A is set to x then show parameter B, else do not show
>   parameter B.

Is that something I can achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. Usually I just write in the description: "B will be ignored if A is set to x". Then I use a condition and a `!If` statement in the resource to use B if A is set to y and use 3 if A is set to x.